# How to put into DataTemplate Unicode Character via binding?

Tags: c#, xaml, unicode, windows-phone-7.1

I try to describe my problem more deeply. I have listbox full of item taken from  `ObservableCollection<show>`, in some cases I need to show [DIAMETER SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2300/index.htm) with properly value at the listbox item area.

For example

[image]

If I would like to have it in every box I would put it hardcoded or make binding with hardcoded value, but only part of items have the value which should be showed with diameter sign.
Here is the fragment of code from the show class, which should return the properly sign

```
public string Thickness 
        {
            get 
            {
                if (thickness == 1)
                {
                    return "&#x2300;28cm";
                }
                else if (thickness == 2)
                {
                    return "&#x2300;50cm";
                }
                else 
                { 
                    return ""; 
                }
            }
        }
```

and fragment of my code from xaml

```
  <TextBlock  
         Foreground="#69AB5C"
         FontSize="15" 
         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
         Text="{Binding Thickness}">
  </TextBlock>
```

and here the question how should I pass from my observable collection the unicode character to xaml

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your problem? The example you shown us seems to be appropriate to what you are trying to achieve, do you not get any results from the code you posted ?

Comment: Yeah, I can see at my screen this same string which I return by get method "&#x2300;28cm". I change the description of the problem I hope it's more clearly now, If I should give more details let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hallelujah!

Here is the solution pal in your property change it from

```
return "&#x2300;50cm";
```

to

```
return ((char)0x2300).ToString();
```

and for `50cm` part you can always use mulitbinding or use char array and bind it to that.
:-)

Comment: @XAMIMAX and what do we have to do if we want to pass &#128190 for instance? it cannot be converted to char (

Comment: @C_M Is that code for a floppy disk? If so use vector graphic for such display. Move the `TextBlock` into a `Grid` or a `StackPanel` and add `ViewBox` to present it. I have also found that you could possibly use this code instead, if you really need to `"\uD83D\uDCBE"`.

Comment: @XAMIMAX yes, this is the code for a floppy disk
your code works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using XML escape characters. You need to use C# character literals:

```
return "\x230028cm";
```